# The functions .prev() and .closest() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is my .cshtml code :

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="FileName" type="hidden" class="hdnFileName" />
        <input type="file" asp-for="UploadFile" accept=".csv" />                
        <button id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-tertiary btnFileSelect" type="button">Browse</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the id of the FileName on click of the upload button.

Script :

```
$(".btnFileSelect").each(function () {
    var btnId = $(this).attr("id");
    //The below code is not working and throwing an undefined value.
    //Tried .closest() which is not working either.
    var fileName = $(this).prev('.hdnFileName').attr('id');
})
```

Variable fileName is showing undefined.
What do I change? Is it being a hidden field the issue?

Comment: Is this your final generated html output? there is no id attribute in that.. If it is taken from your view, please post the final html output.

Comment: @ssilas777 - I suspect this isn't the final output, but rather what they're giving ASP.Net. (There was originally a [tag:c#], but it seemed irrelevant. I should add [tag:asp.net].)

Comment: yeah, it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) doesn't scan, it will only ever return a jQuery object for the previous element (if the selector matches) or an empty one (if it doesn't). From the documentation:

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.

*(jQuery's set-based nature makes that slightly less clear than it could be, but basically you'll get the immediately-previous element if it matches, or none if it doesn't.)*

If you want to scan, use `.prevAll().eq(0)`. Or in this case, I'd probably use [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
var fileName = $(this).siblings('.hdnFileName').attr('id');
```

(I'm assuming something at some point adds an `id` to that element, since it doesn't have one in the markup you've shown.)